# python cvs check out

Tags: python, cvs

I am writing an automation script in python and I need to cvs update from script.

In bash my commands look like this:

```
cvs login
CVS Password:  <here i enter the password>
cvs update -P -d
```

I was using the sub-process module in python to do this, but it fails when it asks for the password.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

The [pyCVS](http://pycvs.sourceforge.net/) module can help you sovle the problem by using a binding.

In general, subprocesses have been, in my experience, much more trouble than just using a library that accomplishes the same thing.

Comment: I don't have permission to import this library. I can use only standard library.

Comment: Well. That certainly makes it more complicated - no way you can get around that requirement?

Comment: Could you describe why? Maybe we could stumble upon a solution.

Comment: I am working on the remote server where I have limited permission. I don't own it and can't upload or download anything from it. Also I am using python2.4 again for the same reasons.

Comment: If you can't upload or download, what's the point of CVS? Just local?

Answer (score 1):

Generally you can pass as arguments like this simplified code:

```
    ## program run.py
    def print_args(name, passwd):
       print name
       print passwd
    ## calling program
    import run
    input_name = raw_input("Enter name ")
    input_passwd = raw_input("Enter password ")
    run.print_args(input_name, input_passwd)
```